# How to cancel all ongoing Promises at once

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Imagine a tool which issues hundreds of requests (`Promise`) through that function:

```js
function send(requestPromise, successFn, failureFn) {
  incrementCounters();
  requestPromise()
    .then(response => successFn(response.headers, response.data))
    .catch(() => failureFn())
    .finally(() => decrementCounters());
}
```

Now, imagine the contacted server decides to deny all subsequent requests due to the client hitting an `API-Rate Limit`.

Assuming the client wants to stop waiting for all the requests: how can the client get all the ongoing Promises to fail?

Thus, the constraints are:

- a response from the server should not be awaited (the `then()` should not be executed)
- the cancellation should trigger both the `catch()` and the `finally()` calls
- even a `Promise` which had been queued up but hasn't yet triggered a call to the server should be cancelled

Comment: Better option: identify the rate limit, and change the JS to never go over it

Comment: @CertainPerformance the Rate-Limit is just an example. There could be many other reasons why the server would end up sending an error back to the client. For example: denying the requests because the "spam" was considered malicious. Not all APIs provide the proper documentation to figure out the conditions under which these kinds of errors happen, and thus programmatically avoiding them ahead of time isn't always an option. (Not to mention how those limits aren't immutable and may very well vary through time. Hell, they might not even be deterministic!)

Comment: For the first 2 constraints you can use a shared [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) which will be replaced with a new one after each cancellation.